# Definitions of Change of Base matrix and Change of base operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I'm am learning linear algebra and I am very confused as to what my textbook is saying about the change of basis operator.

> The discussion is limited to a single finite-dimensional space $V$ and to linear operators on $V$. Begin by examining how the coordinates of $\mathbf{v}\in V$ change as the basis for $V$ change as the basis for $V$ changes. Consider two different bases.
>
> $B=\lbrace \mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,...,\mathbf{x}_n \rbrace$ and $B'=\lbrace \mathbf{y}_1,\mathbf{y}_2,...,\mathbf{y}_n \rbrace$.
>
> It's convenient to regard $B$ as an *old basis* for $V$ and $B'$ as a *new basis* for $V$. Throughout this section $\mathbf{T}$ will denote the linear operation such that
>
> $\mathbf{T} (\mathbf{y}_i)=\mathbf{x}_i$ for $i=1,2,...,n$.
>
> $\mathbf{T}$ is called the ***change of basis operator*** because it maps the new basis vectors in $B'$ to the old basis vectors in $B$. Notice that $[\mathbf{T}]_B=[\mathbf{T}]_{B'}=[\mathbf{I}]_{BB'}$. To see this, observe that 
>   $\mathbf{x}_i=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_j \mathbf{y}_j \implies \mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x}_i)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_j \mathbf{T}(\mathbf{y}_j)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_j \mathbf{x}_j$,
>
> which means $[\mathbf{x}_i]_{B'}=[\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x_i})]_B$.

I am very unclear on what this last line means and what it has to do with the line above or anything that comes after. The rest goes

> So
>
> $[\mathbf{T}]_B = 
>  \begin{pmatrix}
>   [\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x}_1)]_{B} & [\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x}_2)]_{B} & \cdots & [\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x}_1)]_{B}  
>  \end{pmatrix}=$ 
>   $\begin{pmatrix}
>   [\mathbf{x}_1]_{B'} &  [\mathbf{x}_2]_{B'} & \cdots &  [\mathbf{x}_1]_{B'}  
>  \end{pmatrix}= [\mathbf{T}]_{B'}$

What is going on here?

Comment: looks that some *transposition* sign is missing